# How to read option label instead of option value using ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The model can be set and read such like below:

In my Controller

```
$scope.formData = {};
```

In my View

```
<select id="modules" ng-model="formData.read_value">
<option value="module_1">Module Name 1</option>
</select>
```

To fetch back the option value with:

```
$scope.formData.read_value // Will give the value module_1
```

Now, here's my question how to read the value of `Module Name 1` instead of
the value of `module_1`?

I knew to use raw javascript like

```
document.getElementById('modules').options[document.getElementById('modules').selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

can be done and it's working..but how to do in Angularjs? Can anyone help me?

Thanks and have a nice Friday!

Comment: It would be much easier if you changed `value` to just be the string you want to read (in your case `value="Module Name 1"`). Is there anything that prevents you from doing this?

Comment: No, just in case if any ways the angularjs can do